# Radio button onChange function

Tags: javascript, radio-button, onchange

I have a small problem. What is wrong with this function? I have no idea. I need pop-up  alert window when the radio button is selected. Thanks for every reply.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" class="choice" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" class="choice" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" class="choice" value="3">
```

JavaScript

```
var FormFields =
{
    init: function()
    {

        var radio = document.getElementsByName("radioButton");  
        radio.onchange = FormFields.showAlert;  
    },
    showAlert: function()
    {               
        alert("Bye!");
    },
};
```

Comment: Not a resolution, but seem to have an extra `,` at the end there btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList` you'll need to apply the event callback to each input:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("radioButton");
for(var i = 0;i < radios.length;i++){
    radios[i].onchange = FormFields.showAlert;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/H7TdB/

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName gets a list of elements so you are calling onChange on the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName

You want to loop through the elements and apply the onChange.